# Does a solution exist for this discrete time function with variable parameter?

Tags: integration, functions, discrete-time

I am interested in a simple parametric function: $$y(t) = \frac{a}{b} (1-e^{-b t})$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are real parameters greater than zero; $y(0)=0$; and $t$ is time in discrete units, e.g. months or years.

If the value of $a$ can vary arbitrarily by time unit, $a(t)$, is there a solution for $y(t)$?

Note that this function is the solution to the ordinary differential equation: $$ \frac{dy}{dt} = a- b y $$

I am a non-mathematician noob, so any input would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you have more details about $a$ you may get a better answer to your question, but in general you can use this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

Answer (score 0):

> $$y'(t)+by(t) = a(t)$$

By laplace transform:
$$
\mathcal{L}\{y'+by(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{a(t)\}
$$
$$
sY(s)-y(0)+bY(s) = A(s)
$$
$$
Y(s)(s+b)=A(s)+y(0)
$$
$$
y(t) =  \mathcal{L}^{-1}{{A(s)\over s+b}}+y(0)e^{-bt}
$$
Which can be written as:$$ \int_0^ta(u)e^{-b(t-u)}du$$
This is the general formula

Comment: Note that this solution can also be written as $y(t) = \int_0^t a(u) e^{-b(t-u)} du$.